# Background/Wallpaper - Solid color

Tags: c#, background, registry, wallpaper

How do I know if my Wallpaper is a solid color ? 
I know I can check in the registry, under
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors, and then I get a string with 3 numbers indicating RGB.

How can I know if my background is a solid color ? If that string is different than 0 0 0 ?

I am using C#, and I need to know it programatically. (i.e if background is Solid, do X, otherwise, do Y)

Comment: How do you define a _solid color_? Do you refer to the color names defined in the [System.Windows.Media.Colors class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: When you go to wallpaper settings, there's an option for "Solid"

Comment: Shouldn't you check the wallpaper image instead? `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper` ??